# AJAX XMLHttpRequest not working

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to work with ajax. I have two pages: request.html and reply.php.

request.html:

```
<html>
<script language="javascript">
    var xht = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function testAJAX()
    {
        xht.open("get","http://localhost:9999//a.php", true);
        xht.send();
        xht.onreadystatechange=function() { 
            if (xht.readyState==4) {
                alert("Text: "+xht.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  btn
  <input name="btn" type="submit" id="btn" onClick="testAJAX();" value="Submit" />
</form>
</html>
```

reply.php:

```
<?php
echo 'hi';
?>
```

The problem is that I don't get a response via `xht.responseText` and with `xht.responseXML` I get `null` and with `xht.status` I get `0`.

I asked the link `http://localhost:9999//a.php` via browser and got `hi` correctly.

P.S: I tried this on Chrome 29.0.1547.18 and Maxthon v4.1.1

any ideas..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to mention `"http://localhost"`.

The main mistake is you have given the input type as Submit If it is submit the form will be submitted first the click event will not trigger. Change the input type to button.
If you want to do form submission do it in java script

The corrected code is below.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  btn
  <input name="btn" type="button" id="btn" onClick="testAJAX();" value="Submit" />
   // change type to button
</form> 

var xht = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function testAJAX()
    {
        xht.open("get","a.php", true); /// Change to a.php
        xht.send();
        xht.onreadystatechange=function() { 
            if (xht.readyState==4) {
                alert("Text: "+xht.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this answer requires the html page to be on the same level as a.php 
the answer is correct.
but why AJAX doesn't work with `onSubmit()` event?

Comment: try the new edit i have made change type="button". it will work

Comment: Its because you are submitting the form to the server.But ajax is client side request. However, you are asking the button to submit the form to server side

Comment: @Krishna Kishore Shetty onsubmit = return false has the same effect of not giving submit button. Submit button is used to submit the form to server and if form submission is not needed why to use submit button. And I agree with your opinion of following the HTML structure correctly

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [SarathPrakash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2036918/sarathsprakash)'s answer, I would like to point out that there is nothing wrong with specifying localhost. It will still work as long as the PHP file's address is valid.

You can also have the submit button. But you'll have to modify the form opening tag as follows:-

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="return false">
```

This is will stop the default behaviour of the form being submitted. Although in my         opinion, it is best to avoid it altogether, and just stick with assigning the correct event handler to the onclick attribute.

Also, it is good practice to follow the correct syntax for HTML documents.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Your title here </title>
  <script type="text/javascript"> Your script here </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  Your main document text here. Forms, tables etc.
 </body>
</html>
```

For a simple tutorial, you could try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).